# JDBC - NetBeans x MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, rdbms

I'm trying to create a **Java Application** in **NetBeans** which allows the user to use most **MySQL** RDBMS functionalities through a GUI. I have successfully written the code for the following :

1. Creating a Database
2. Dropping a Database
3. Creating a Table giving options for table name, no. of columns, data type for every column

I'm stuck at the part where the user gets to insert a record in the table that was just created. I'm unable to figure out how the "insert into table values ..." query can be dynamically created and passed depending on the table the user wants to enter this record in. The table could have any number of columns, of course.

Comment: can you share your code so we can clearify what 's wrong in your code

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help),  also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Finally please read this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then google "dynamic sql java example" and follow any of the examples.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is the correct method, but when I faced this same problem in the past, this is how I solved it :
I ran this query to find the number of columns in the table

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_catalog = 'database_name' AND table_name = 'table_name'
```

Then created a dynamic sql query based on no of columns:

```
    String sql = "Insert into tablename values(";
    for(int i = 1;i<=columns;i++){
        sql += "?";
        if (i < columns) {
        sql += ", ";
        }
    }
    sql+=");";
```

Then fired a Prepared Statement

```
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

If you also don't know the constraints and datatype of the columns, try parsing

```
    desc tablename
```

I know this must be the shittiest workaround, but it worked for me;)